# Add enum value with Byte Buddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy

Let's say I've got an enum like the following

```
public enum BindingType {
  BINDING_OPEN("M1+O", "Open", true),
  BINDING_SAVE("M1+S", "Save", true),
  ...

  private BindingType(
       final String sequence,
       final String keyLabel,
       final boolean reserved) {
    this.sequence = sequence;
    this.keyLabel = keyLabel;
    this.reserved = reserved;
  }
}
```

At JVM startup I'd like to add an additional value, for example

```
BINDING_CUSTOM("M1+U", "Custom", true)
```

Can this be done using Byte Buddy's `AgentBuilder`?

Comment: **Interface constants** would be a more logical choice, for an open ended value domain. Easier and has a more flexible architecture.

Comment: @JoopEggen you're right, but this is part of a framework which I need to enhance, and that's why the agent. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An enum is nothing but a `public static final` field of the enumeration type. You can certainly declare such a field for the enumeration type and instrument the static initializer via `builder.executable(isTypeInitializer())` to set the field to a value by calling the class's constructor.

Additionally, you would probably need to instrument the class's `values` method to return the additional constant with the other values and the `valueOf` method to resolve the additional constant.

Enumerations are merely synthetic sugar for this combination of methods and a field. Byte Buddy offers convenience for creating new enumerations but if altering existing enumerations, you need to take some manual steps.